# Session Persistence in GCP HTTP/S Load Balancers not working as expected

Tags: networking, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I've been working for years with other Load balancers, so I expected GCP load balancers to work in the same way as others when using session persistence settings.

Unfortunately, **enabling session persistence for backends in GCP LB doesn't seem to send all the requests for a certain client to a single backend server (neither using Cookies or IP session persistence options)**

**Is it a known bug/behavior or something that I can solve by myself?**

---

I made this quick test:

- I've created a new HTTP LB and assigned a new external IP to it.
- I've pointed a backend service to an instance group with 2 instances.
- As my backend server is running apache and mod_php, I've created a simple PHP script (called get_up.php) to show the server IP address (see the code in below)
- Finally, I ran a quick curl script inside a loop, pointing to the $LBIP/get_ip.php to see what happens.

If I do the same, let's say, in Rackspace, I get always the same IP as the outcome but in GCP I see that I can reach any of my two backend servers randomly.

This is my PHP test script:

```
<?php
$realIP = file_get_contents("http://ipecho.net/plain");
echo "My Ip is " . $realIP;
echo "\n";
?>
```

And this is my test run:

```
➜  ~ while true; do curl -b cookie.txt -c cookie.txt $IP/get_ip.php; sleep 1 ; done
My Ip is 35.193.16.20
My Ip is 35.193.16.20
My Ip is 35.193.16.20
My Ip is 35.193.16.20
My Ip is 104.197.18.77
My Ip is 104.197.18.77
My Ip is 104.197.18.77
My Ip is 35.193.16.20
My Ip is 104.197.18.77
My Ip is 35.193.16.20
My Ip is 35.193.16.20
My Ip is 104.197.138.72
```

---

- Edit - Curl command to send cookies, based on BillThor comment. Same results.

---

- Edit - Solution details.

---

Session persistence works well when it's used with single-zone instance groups. I had to sacrifice the usage of multi-zone instance groups until this is solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cookies for persistence you need to provide a cookie jar for curl to use. Otherwise each request looks like it is coming from a new user. Try a command like:

```
while true; do -b cookie.txt -c cookie.txt curl $IP/get_ip.php; sleep 1 ; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the results are still the same :( 
I've opened a ticket to GCP enterprise support to see if they can bring some light to this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems session persistence is not "yet" available with GCP Load balancers.
In order to persist the SAML token between my IDP and the SPs, I had to install NGINX PLUS server in front.

This can be deployed using Cloud Launcher: [NGINX PLUS](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/nginx-public/nginx-plus?q=nginx)